# How does a 32 bit or 64 bit OS affect the data type range

Tags: c++, c

How does a 32 bit or a 64 bit OS affect the range of a data type.?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean how does it effect `sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(long)`, etc.?

On a 32-bit machine pointers will be 4 bytes (ie, `sizeof(int*) == 4`) and on a 64-bit machine pointers will be 8 bytes. Beyond this, I don't think the C or C++ standards require anything about the size of primitive types based on the OS architecture (and in fact I'm not even sure if the pointer sizes are standard, though it would be rather odd to have `sizeof(int*) < 8` on a 64-bit machine, and rather wasteful to have `sizeof(int*) > 4` on a 32-bit machine)

Comment: too much guess work for my taste

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't *directly* affect the sizes of the fundamental types.

It's not 100% clear what the definition of a "32-bit" or "64-bit" OS is. Very commonly a 32-bit OS will use 32-bit pointers, and a 64-bit OS will use 64-bit pointers.

For typical systems with monolithic linear address spaces, the sizes of certain typedefs such as `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` will typically be the same as the size of a pointer.

The C and C++ standards say very little about this. They specify *minimum* sizes for various types (`char` is at least 8 bits, `short` at least 16, `int` 16, `long` 32, and `long long` 64, with each type in that list being at least as wide as its predecessor). The languages *permit* some very odd implementations that you're not likely to see in real life (11-bit bytes with 7-byte pointers and 9-byte `long`, for example).

The actual sizes are typically determined by the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) for a given system -- which could be different for different 64-bit systems on the same hardware, for example.

It happens that (almost) all the systems I've used happen to have all pointer types the same size, and use the same size for pointers and type `long`, but you shouldn't count on that.

Ideally, you should write your code to be as portable as you can reasonably make it. Use the `sizeof` operator rather than making assumptions about how big a given type is (though `char` is absolutely guaranteed to be exactly 1 byte). If you need types of specified sizes, use the typedefs in `<stdint.h>` (or, in C++, `<cstdint>`).

Comment: Does a computation like multiplying two double values ->         -329.0000 * 0.000000 gives result -0.000000 in 32 bit and 0.000000 in 64 bit?

Comment: @james: I can't think of any reason why it should. `double` is often (but not necessarily) the same on 32-bit and 64-bit systems; it's typically 64-bit IEEE. Why do you think the behavior would differ?

Answer (score -3):

It doesn't necessarily affect it at all.  It just means that pointers will will be long instead of int.  but the types don't change.   and that's only if actually compiled as 64 bit.

Comment: Pointers are neither `long` nor `int`. Pointers are pointers. They might (or might not) happen to be the same size as one or both of those types, but the criteria for determining the size of a pointer are quite different from those for determining the size of an integer type. The sizes of integer types very commonly do vary between 32-bit and 64-bit systems. And pointer types are "data types" just as much as integer types are.

Comment: yes, you'r exactly right.  I was really  referring to actual memory pointer in assembly

Comment: But the question is about C and C++, not about assembly.

Comment: well regardless of the language, the difference in a 64 bit OS is that memory addresses, and thus native memory pointers can be 64 bit integers instead of just 32 bit integers.

Comment: Nope. In C and C++, *addresses are not integers*. (Yes, they're made of bits; that doesn't make them integers. Yes, you can perform restricted arithmetic on them; that doesn't make them integers either.) And your statement that "the types don't change" is also mistaken; for example, Linux on x86 generally has 32-bit `long`, and Linux on x86_64 generally has 64-bit `long` (though neither is required by the language).

Comment: @KeithThompson - **compilers** for Linux on x86 generally have 32-bit `long`. They're an important part of the food chain...

Comment: look up integer in the dictionary.  It's a math concept.  I'm not talking about "int"s  I'm talking about integers.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Good point. Typically the ABI specifies the sizes of the various integer types; both the OS and the compiler(s) have to consistently use and/or implement what the ABI specifies.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing: The dictionary definition of "integer" does not support your claim. You specifically referred to "int" and "long" in your answer; those are C and C++ type names, not mathematical terms. In any case, the C and C++ standards have their own definitions of "integer types", which you're disregarding.

Comment: @KeithThompson blah blah spec spec.  What I said in my comment was that 64bit OS use integers of 64 bit length to define memory addressess and this memory references (=pointers).  Deal with it.

Comment: I am dealing with it -- by telling you that you're wrong. There's some correct information in there, but it's hidden by your incorrect and inconsistent use of terminology, and by your refusal to admit the possibility that you might be mistaken. In C and C++, integers and addresses are different things; it's that simple.

Comment: so I guess if I use typdef and call an int a thomson, a thomson is somehow not an int.    Well sure, conceptually and for type-checking purposes.  But "call" it what you want, it "IS" an int.  My answer was a casual description.  My subsequent comments are correct as they are referring to an integer as "whole numbers".  and guess what? pointers in the end are "whole numbers" that can be added to or subtracted from or used as a memory address

Comment: @AwokeKnowing: One last comment. Integers can be multiplied and divided. Can addresses?

Comment: see, that seals you lack of understanding.  If B "is a" A, that doesn't mean A is a B  .    And yes, if you multiply an integer representing an address by 2, it points to a memory location exactly twice the distance from memory address 0.  Bet that blows you spec mind apart, but it's just simple math.